# .Net MVC Razor - Concatenating string inside ternary operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, ternary-operator, string-concatenation

How can I concatenate the following string to render correctly when used inside a ternary operator?

```
<input @(field.Type == "number" ? $"data-val-number=The field {field.Label}  must be a number" : "") />
```

The above doesn't render correctly - it outputs as follows missing the double quotes:

```
<input type="text" data-val-number=The field Time must be a number />
```

Comment: Your code works as expected (showing the message for number type inputs) when i added the closing tag for the input element `<input @(field.Type == "number" ? $"data-val-number=The field {field.Label}  must be a number" : "") />`

Comment: @Shyju if you look at the source when it renders, its missing the double quotes: `<input  type="text" data-val-number=The field Time must be a number />`

Comment: Normally your would be able to use Razor's conditional attributes, but they do not seem to work with `data-val-*` attributes, so you would need an `if/else` block to generate the input. But the fact your manually adding an attribute used by client side validation suggest a design problem. You should be using conditional validation attributes to generate them.

Comment: Alternatively you could try `<input @(field.Type == "number" ? "@Html.Raw(data-val-number=$\"The field {field.Label} must be a number\")" : null) />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about escaped quotes?

```
<input @Html.Raw(field.Type == "number" ? $"data-val-number=\"The field {field.Label}  must be a number\"" : "") />
```

Comment: You should probably test you code first to understand why it does not work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your hint! Added Html.Raw. Now the escaped quotes are rendered like i expected.